Authentication with Negotiate in ASP.NET with docker container
After endless attempts to Negotiate authorization, I turn here.) The application itself works in Docker, files such as krb5.conf and keytab file have also been added, but there is still an authorization error. Here is the complete error -
Microsoft.Asp Net Core.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: Generic Failure
Docker File:

Auth used in Application:

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?
The solution to the problem is Microsoft.Asp Net Core.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: Generic Failure

DON'T SCREAM!!!

xD
I'm not shouting), it just happened that way

All caps or all bolds is shouting for the last 30 years. Post your code as text, not images. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled.

From what I managed to gather with a magnifying glass: There is nothing that tells the service which keytab to use.

Your KRB5_KTNAME= is a separate RUN, and since environment is per-process, its effects just disappear between RUNs. (More to that, the command doesn't even seem to export the variable to environment anyway.)

The kinit is useless because servers don't need their own tickets (only clients do) – instead, servers must have access to the actual keytab, as that's how they decrypt tickets from clients.


You probably need to use the ENV option, as in:

ENV KRB5_KTNAME=/etc/srvupsp.keytab


OK, I'll try your option, I just thought kinit should be in the dockerfile too.
THANKS!

After the insertion, the same error still remains. (
